# Purpose of gradle wrapper.jar in my libraries

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to add libraries to my project and for some reason I am seeing a gradle folder with gradle wrapper.jar and artifactory.gradle.

what are the purposes of these files? Do I need to toch them or invoke them before adding this library?

Comment: wrapper explained : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll divide the answer in two parts, depending on files:

**gradle-wrapper.jar**:

This jar contains a packaged version of `Gradle`. It's recommended to have a wrapper for each projects that uses `Gradle` for two reasons:

1. The wrapper can ensure to have the same version of `Gradle` for everyone that will use your project.
2. If someone hasn't `Gradle` installed, he can use the wrapper to execute commands.

You can't "invoke" the wrapper but you can use the same `Gradle` commands with the wrapper.

**artifactory.gradle**

This gradle file can be a random file with some scripts/tasks inside but I'm pretty sure (as the name suggest) that it contains a script to upload artifacts to [Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/open-source/).

You can execute its task with the wrapper (or a local `Gradle`).

> Do I need to toch them or invoke them before adding this library?

No